# gulp not found when deploying angular 2 + rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angular, heroku, deployment

I am currently trying to deploy my angular 2 app with Rails 5 back end to heroku. In order to do this I have been following this tutorial: https://www.angularonrails.com/deploy-angular-2rails-5-app-heroku/#comment-39250 .

The tutorial has been going well expect for the last part when deploying to heroku using: `git push heroku master`. I get the following error:

```
Counting objects: 254, done. 
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (232/232), done.
Writing objects: 100% (254/254), 158.00 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 254 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version (latest stable) via semver.io...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 6.9.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.10.8
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Pruning any extraneous modules
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        
remote:        > angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_924023d394206e157329026627746427/client
remote:        > gulp check.versions && gulp build.bundle.rxjs && npm prune && gulp webdriver && gulp print.banner
remote:        
remote:        sh: 1: gulp: not found
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_924023d394206e157329026627746427/client/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_924023d394206e157329026627746427/client/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_924023d394206e157329026627746427/client/.npmrc"
remote:        npm ERR! node v6.9.1
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
remote:        npm ERR! file sh
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR! syscall spawn
remote:        npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall: `gulp check.versions && gulp build.bundle.rxjs && npm prune && gulp webdriver && gulp print.banner`
remote:        npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall script 'gulp check.versions && gulp build.bundle.rxjs && npm prune && gulp webdriver && gulp print.banner'.
remote:        npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
remote:        npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
remote:        npm ERR! not with npm itself.
remote:        npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
remote:        npm ERR!     gulp check.versions && gulp build.bundle.rxjs && npm prune && gulp webdriver && gulp print.banner
remote:        npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
remote:        npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-seed
remote:        npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
remote:        npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed
remote:        npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_924023d394206e157329026627746427/client/npm-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:        
remote:        - Gulp may not be tracked in package.json
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to aqueous-castle-46289.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/aqueous-castle-46289.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/aqueous-castle-     46289.git'
```

Here too is my package.json as done in the tutorial:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-seed",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Seed for Angular 2 apps",
  "repository": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build.dev": "gulp build.dev --color",
    "build.dev.watch": "gulp build.dev.watch --color",
    "build.e2e": "gulp build.e2e --color",
    "build.prod": "gulp build.prod --color",
    "build.test": "gulp build.test --color",
    "build.test.watch": "gulp build.test.watch --color",
    "docs": "npm run gulp -- build.docs --color && npm run gulp -- serve.docs --color",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "e2e.live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "karma": "karma",
    "karma.start": "karma start",
    "postinstall": "typings install && gulp check.versions && npm prune && gulp build.prod",
    "reinstall": "npm cache clean && npm install",
    "serve.coverage": "remap-istanbul -b src/ -i coverage/coverage-final.json -o coverage -t html && npm run gulp -- serve.coverage --color",
    "serve.dev": "gulp serve.dev --color",
    "serve.e2e": "gulp serve.e2e --color",
    "serve.prod": "gulp serve.prod --color",
    "start": "gulp serve.dev --color",
    "tasks.list": "gulp --tasks-simple --color",
    "test": "gulp test --color",
    "webdriver-start": "webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "author": "Minko Gechev <mgechev>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "es6-module-loader": "^0.17.8",
    "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "~0.19.25",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.10",
    "async": "^1.4.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.3",
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.2",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.12",
    "colorguard": "^1.1.1",
    "connect": "^3.4.1",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.1.0",
    "connect-livereload": "^0.5.3",
    "cssnano": "^3.5.2",
    "doiuse": "^2.3.0",
    "event-stream": "^3.3.2",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "express-history-api-fallback": "^2.0.0",
    "extend": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cached": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-inject": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-inline-ng2-template": "^1.1.2",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.1.0",
    "gulp-shell": "~0.5.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "git+https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps.git#master",
    "gulp-template": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "^4.3.3",
    "gulp-typedoc": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "~2.12.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.3",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
    "is-ci": "^1.0.8",
    "isstream": "^0.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
    "karma": "~0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.5",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.8",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
    "postcss-reporter": "^1.3.3",
    "protractor": "^3.0.0",
    "remap-istanbul": "git+https://github.com/SitePen/remap-istanbul.git#master",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.0",
    "semver": "^5.1.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.10.2",
    "slash": "~1.0.0",
    "stream-series": "^0.1.1",
    "stylelint": "^5.3.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^5.0.0",
    "systemjs-builder": "^0.15.14",
    "tiny-lr": "^0.2.1",
    "traceur": "^0.0.91",
    "ts-node": "^0.7.1",
    "tslint": "^3.7.0-dev.2",
    "tslint-stylish": "2.1.0-beta",
    "typedoc": "^0.3.12",
    "typescript": "~1.8.10",
    "typings": "^0.7.12",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "yargs": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

I am sure the problem most likely resides with the package.json and its inability to find 'gulp'.

I have also tried to follow the instructions of the following person: https://www.angularonrails.com/deploy-angular-2rails-5-app-heroku/#comment-38286 as it appears that they had a similar problem - however their instructions dont appear to be very clear and whatever I've been able to infer from them hasnt worked. If you know what they mean let me know.

I would appreciate any help that I can get.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Go to your app folder > Run `heroku buildpacks` > Post the output here.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I've just encountered this error as well doing the same tutorial. If you check the log you see the following error:

> Node version not specified in package.json

If you google that you'll find [this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version)

Use the engines section of your package.json to specify the version of Node.js to use on Heroku.

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "a really cool app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.4"
}
```

}

This should get your installation going again.